# Is there a way to have a file in one repository but not in another?

Tags: git, heroku, github

I have a node.js app with a settings file that needs to be in the repo when I push to Heroku, but I would like to share my project on github sans my API-keys, session secrets, etc...

I know I can add the file to .gitignore, but then it won't push to Heroku.

Otherwise, I've been manually copying files from one repo to another whenever I make changes.

Is there a better way.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692541/pushing-gitignore-files-to-specific-remote) asked and answered two years ago, but the warning about "much discipline" made me a little gun-shy with the branching solution, so I thought I'd ask if anything had changed.

Also, I'd like to avoid the `environment variables` method mentioned in that answer if at all possible because some of the API keys are likely to change a few times over the course of development (from personal dev keys to corporate keys), as will session secret, database passwords, etc... ("1234" works while it's broken on localhost, but I'll probably do something longer but still memorable while in beta, and would eventually replace all my tokens with random hashes eventually)

I also checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836742/using-git-how-do-i-ignore-a-file-in-one-branch-but-have-it-committed-in-another) but the consensus there seems to be that the accepted answer doesn't work, and I was hesitant to try it with my API key

Comment: Wy not just [configuration variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)? They're easy to change, and if you need multiple environmentes (test, production, etc.), you can just create multiple apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use environmental variables for this, their exact purpose is that they can be easily different on Heroku versus your local machine.

`heroku config` lists environmental variables accessible from your dynos, and is exactly where API keys need to go.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is designed around using environment variables for configuration, so trying to avoid it is likely to be futile. See this link for the rationale : http://12factor.net/config