# Reading secret config file on Heroku without using env vars

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using the [Google Cloud Pub Sub API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/prereqs) with NodeJS, as [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/). I'm using Heroku to run my server.

The sample code on the Node JS + Pub Sub page asks me to specify a path to a file:

```
pubsub = gcloud.pubsub({
    projectId: 'my-project',
    keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
});
```

I typically use Heroku's config vars to store secrets and API keys, but in this case it seems that the GCloud API **requires** me to specify the path to a file. So, I would need to check in a file into Heroku, but not my GitHub repo.

I have tried the following: [Pushing .gitignore files to specific remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692541/pushing-gitignore-files-to-specific-remote) and [How can I upload my application to github but remove sensitive authorization information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221657/how-can-i-upload-my-application-to-github-but-remove-sensitive-authorization-info/3223543#3223543) but the trouble is that once I force add (`git add -f keyfile.json`) the json file and make a commit out of it and make a new branch, I can't push that commit to Heroku because when I do `git push heroku master`, it says `Everything is up to date`. In any case, that seems very messy. There has got to be a cleaner way to make Google Cloud work with Heroku.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was answered by the lovely folks over at GoogleCloudPlatform: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/issues/761

It's not mentioned in the code sample in the documentation, but you can just add a credentials object and pass that to your config. The credentials object can read env vars.

More information here: <s>https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/authorization</s>.
**Updated link:** https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/pubsub/latest/global.html#ClientConfig

Comment: this link seems to be dead: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/authorization
redirecting to generic page: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/libraries

Answer (score 0):

Not for nodejs but for GO (GOLANG) keep each field value as a separate key in environment variables and then you will need to do something like this, create struct, convert to json (**replacing every `\\n` to `\n` in the private_key**), feed into option.**WithCredentialsJSON**:

```
type credentialsData struct {
    Type                    string `json:"type"`
    ProjectId               string `json:"project_id"`
    PrivateKeyId            string `json:"private_key_id"`
    PrivateKey              string `json:"private_key"`
    ClientEmail             string `json:"client_email"`
    ClientId                string `json:"client_id"`
    AuthUri                 string `json:"auth_uri"`
    TokenUri                string `json:"token_uri"`
    AuthProviderX509CertUrl string `json:"auth_provider_x509_cert_url"`
    ClientX509CertUrl       string `json:"client_x509_cert_url"`
}

func firebase_init() *firebase.App {
    backSlashFix := strings.Replace(os.Getenv("FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY"), "\\n", "\n", -1)
    json_cred := &credentialsData{
        Type:                    os.Getenv("FIREBASE_ACCOUNT_TYPE"),
        ProjectId:               os.Getenv("FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID"),
        PrivateKeyId:            os.Getenv("FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID"),
        PrivateKey:              backSlashFix,
        ClientEmail:             os.Getenv("FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL"),
        ClientId:                os.Getenv("FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID"),
        AuthUri:                 os.Getenv("FIREBASE_AUTH_URI"),
        TokenUri:                os.Getenv("FIREBASE_TOKEN_URI"),
        AuthProviderX509CertUrl: os.Getenv("FIREBASE_AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL"),
        ClientX509CertUrl:       os.Getenv("FIREBASE_CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL"),
    }

    bytes, e := json.Marshal(json_cred)
    if e != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Could not create json from credentials struct", e))
    }
    opt := option.WithCredentialsJSON([]byte(string(bytes)))
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), &firebase.Config{ProjectID: "<your project id>"}, opt)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("error initializing app: %v", err))
    }

    return app
}
```